Rainbird ESP-4Si controller. In manual mode zone1 turns on no matter what the controller dial is set on
I have a Rainbird ESP-4Si controller with 3 zones wired. When i turn the knob to zone 1 it turns on zone 1 only. When I turn to zone 2 it comes on for 2 seconds and zone 2 shuts down and zone 1 comes on. When I turn the knob to zone 3 it comes on and stays on but zone 1 also runs. This only started after I changed the sprinkler heads on zone 1. I replaced them with identical new heads so could I have caused this problem with the new heads?

how could the replacement of a pipe affect a program in a controller?

Is there a possibility that the wiring at the heads got changed, damaged, shorted or any something similar?

@Michael Karas,  A sprinkler system does not have wires to the sprinkler heads. the wires only go to the zone valves that open and close each zone, unless it is controlled with an indexing valve. Then there are no wires or zone valves.  This may be the case with the OP's system.
